# How can I list the categories according to the quantity they were sold in winter from less to many?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are my tables:

**Sales**

| id | product_code | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 3334 | 19.07.2019 12:29:00 |
| 02 | 4674 | 29.04.2019 03:20:00 |

**Products**

| product_code | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3334 | 1 |
| 4674 | 2 |

**Categories**

| ID | product_category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pastry |
| 2 | drinks |

I need to list the categories in ascending order, which were sold in winter. Quantity is considered as a repetition of `product_code` in the `sales` table.

Expected output:

| Product_category | quantity_sold |
| --- | --- |
| Drinks | 56 |
| Pastry | 134 |

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT a.product_code,
       a.product_name,
       count(*) as Quantity
  FROM products a, 
       Sales b
 WHERE a.product_code = b.product_code
   AND sales.sales_date 
       BETWEEN '01.01.2019 00:00:00' AND '01.02.2019 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY a.product_code,
         a.product_name;
```

But it gives me multiple errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be useful if you provide the error that executing your query gives.

Comment: Guessing game (no errors noted so far) - SQL Server complains on the dates (between)(?) Strange (old) joining syntax there, intended?

Comment: Side notes: use an unambiguous date format such as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, and use a half-open interval `s.sales_date >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND s.sales_date < '2019-01-02 00:00:00'`

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You assigned an alias `b` to `sales` table but then still referred to it using its full name in the WHERE clause: sales.sales_date. change this to `b.sales_date`